# How can I fix the phone bricked?

Tags: settings, screen, unbricking, usb-debugging, developer-options

My phone has just bricked after I do something using ADB and now I can't do anything to it. I can't hard reset, The volume part is broken off and does not respond only power button, The touch screen is frozen and not working but I can see the time still running. I have my phone turned USB debugging on but I forgot to always allow this computer. I tried many recovery tools but most of them can't work without USB debugging. My phone is old it uses a micro USB port. I am able to connect it to my working phone and show Its own files. Does this have an app that can reset my bricked phone or software on pc that can fix my problem? Thank you.

Edit: My phone has android version 9.0

Comment: there exist several ways to recover data from ancient phones, but can't tell a single without knowing phone model and android version

Comment: My Android version is 9.0 and I don't know much about its model but I know It's not Samsung model

Comment: Most Probably you are in a recoverable situation. So your phone can be flashed in EDL mode but most manufacturers have their EDL mode hardware locked. So you probably need to go to someone who has little expertice in hardware to get into EDL mode.